# Accessing superclass members

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I want to create a superclass that has just two fields: Id and Timestamp, and have a class that can use any descendants of that superclass. Kind of like using generics, but I know it will at least have an Id and timestamp field.

I could use reflection to look up properties, but I'll be using it to deal with thousands of objects at a time and am under the impression that I'll take a big performance hit (please correct me if I'm wrong).

Here's a simple, dumb example of what I want to do. Say I have the following superclass:

```
public class Shape
{
    public double Area { get; set; }
}
```

I also implement square, which descends from Shape:

```
class Square : Shape
{
    public int SideLength { get; set; }
    // more stuff
}
```

What I want to do is make a ShapeHandler class which accepts any type of shape and can get its area. But the following code is **incorrect**:

```
class ShapeHandler<Shape>
{
    private Shape MyShape;

    public double GetArea()
    {
        return MyShape.Area;
    }
}
```

I'd love to be able to do this:

```
var sh = new ShapeHandler<Square>();
sh.GetArea();
```

Does this question make sense? Is there a correct way to do what I want to do?

Comment: Not sure if the following is your problem, but perhaps make the `Area` property with a protected setter and public getter. In the setter of `Square.SideLength`, calculate and set the `Area` value. The approach with generics is doctoring around the problem without solving it, since `Square` **is a** `Shape`, hence Shape.Area must/should provide correct value if the Shape object in question is a Square...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your generic syntax wrong:

```
class ShapeHandler<Shape>
```

Is making your `ShapeHandler` generic, but its not limiting it to `Shape`, its actually calling the Type parameter "Shape".

What you want to do is:

```
public class ShapeHandler<T> where T: Shape
{
    private T MyShape;

    public double GetArea()
    {
        return MyShape.Area;
    }
}
```

This means that your `ShapeHandler` can only be instantiated with a type (`T`) of `Shape` (or something that inherits from `Shape`)

One thing to ask yourself is:

### Why do you need this?

Does it make sense to use generics when you can just use a parameter of type `Shape`?

Based on your edit about logging certain properties, consider this:

You have two objects, a shape and a square:

```
var square = new Square() { Area = 4.0, SideLength = 2 };
var shape = new Shape() { Area = 3.0 };
```

And you want to print out the Area property (they are both technically `Shape` so they both have the `Area` property.  You can make a method that accepts a `Shape` parameter and then you can access anything that a Shape has:

```
public static void LogArea(Shape shape)
{
    Console.WriteLine(shape.Area);
}
```

I made a fiddle to demonstrate [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/o12SOZ)

Comment: Very true; though I very much doubt a generic is needed here at all (at least as written)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I was editing when you commented.  Wanted to address the problem first, then add some further thoughts.  Not sure if you were the downvote or not but whomever did I would like feedback as to why.  There are obviously issues with the OP's approach beyond the code not compiling, I am addressing some of it here but I think its a stretch to give a complete code review / tutoring session here...

Comment: Okay. So if I make a ShapeHandler interface, how do I extend from it? ShapeHandler : IShapeHandler<T> where...? I don't know how to appease the syntax gods here.

Comment: @Slothario the thing is you don't need generics here.  It sounds like you might have an XY Problem.  Explain what you code problem is, not the problem you are having with your implementation

Comment: @maccettura I'm trying to make something that reads and writes objects to logs. I know those objects will have at least an Id and a TimeStamp, but may have other fields too as it's in a CSV format. I believe I need a generic so I can read in a list of any kind of object that descends from my superclass.

Comment: I'm not the DV, I think you have the right answer (basically the same as mine after the edit)

Comment: @Slothario well if the objects all have those properties, then whatever their common class or interface is should be the parameter type.  Generics aren't necessarily needed.  See the last code sample in my answer, its not using generics and still able to access the Area because Shape is the parameter type

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the `Shape` you are looking for.

```
class ShapeHandler<Shape>
{
    private Shape MyShape;
```

The `Shape` in that snippet is *not* the `Shape` class, it is a generic type argument *called* `Shape`. For all intents and purposes, as written, its an `object`.

If you really want `ShapeHandler` to be generic, you would typically do an interface (`IShape`) and a generic type constraint:

```
class ShapeHandler<T> where T : IShape
```

Though the constraint can be against a concrete class as well. But there's no real reason for it to be generic *at all*, just take in/store a base class reference and call it good.

```
 class ShapeHandler
  {
      public ShapeHandler(Shape shape)
      {
          MyShape = shape;
      }
  }
```

One other thing, `MyShape` is a field in your code and so should be camelCase (`myShape`)